# What is H18 (Canada)?

Tags: application, university, transcript-of-records, canada

I'm currently doing university level continuing education in Quebec, Canada.  As part of my degree, I want to do some courses from another university online.  I've talked to my chairperson, and he validated certain courses.  So I made an application this January, and recently received a conditional offer of admission.

One of the conditions was receiving the official transcript from my current university.  No problem, right?  Simply ask my home university to send them the document: they have an online form for it, which I filled out, and off it went.

What I'm concerned about is that under the Documents to send is listed "Official transcript" and under details, "with H18."  What is H18?  Does it refer to something that must be on the document, or something about the university?

[image: Screenshot of missing documents]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

H18 stands for Hiver 2018 (Winter 2018), that is, the current semester.

Similarly, E18 is Été 2018 (Summer 2018) and A18 is Automne 2018 (Fall 2018).

Source: I'm from Québec, and I recognize my former University software in this screen capture.

Comment: Is there any other short form, perhaps for Summer, etc? Could be useful to supplement the answer :)

Comment: The Université de Montréal [uses E18](http://dms.umontreal.ca/fr/programmes-et-cours/cours-et-horaires/0/4/2/coursid/0) which makes sense with the french word été for summer.

Comment: @AndrewT. Good idea, I have edited the answer to add the other semesters